# How to search for text matches for separate columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **(original)** like below:

```
      Player Name       Headline
1     LeBron James      LeBron James suggests 5-10 games before playoff
2     LeBron James      LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday 
3     LeBron James      LeBron James overcomes Pelicans with 34/13/12
4     LeBron James      Kyrie Irving (groin) plans to play on Tuesday   
5     LeBron James      LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday      
6     LeBron James      LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday   
7     LeBron James      Kevin Love (hip) is questionable 
8     Ryan Anderson     Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday   
9     Ryan Anderson     Ryan Anderson out with respiratory infection   
10    Ryan Anderson     Anderson (rest) not playing
```

I want to remove any rows that do not have any `(text)` in the Headline column. Also, I want to have two new columns labeled `Injury/Rest` and `Location` like below. This is what I do to accomplish this:

```
df['Location'] = df.Headline.str.extract('\((.*)\)')[0]
df = df[df['Location'].notnull()]
df['Injury/Rest'] = np.where(df['Location'].eq('rest'), 'Rest', 'Injury')
```

**New Output**:

```
        Player Name    Headline                                       Location    Injury/Rest
    --  -------------  ---------------------------------------------  ----------  -------------
     2  LeBron James   LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday     groin       Injury
     4  LeBron James   Kyrie Irving (groin) plans to play on Tuesday  groin       Injury
     5  LeBron James   LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday       rest        Rest
     6  LeBron James   LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday      leg         Injury
     7  LeBron James   Kevin Love (hip) is questionable               hip         Injury
     8  Ryan Anderson  Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday  flu         Injury
    10  Ryan Anderson  Anderson (rest) not playing                    rest        Rest
```

**I want to convert my original dataframe to this (NEW):**

```
        Player Name    Headline                                       Headline_Player Location    Injury/Rest   Status
    --  -------------  ---------------------------------------------  -------------   ---------   -----------   -----------
     2  LeBron James   LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday     Lebron James    groin       Injury        probable for Thursday
     4  LeBron James   Kyrie Irving (groin) plans to play on Tuesday  Kyrie Irving    groin       Injury        plans to play on Tuesday
     5  LeBron James   LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday       Lebron James    rest        Rest          questionable Tuesday
     6  LeBron James   LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday      Lebron Jame     leg         Injury        will start on Saturday
     7  LeBron James   Kevin Love (hip) is questionable               Kevin Love      hip         Injury        is questionable
     8  Ryan Anderson  Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday  Ryan Anderson   flu         Injury        returns against Cavs on Sunday
    10  Ryan Anderson  Anderson (rest) not playing                    Ryan Anderson   rest        Rest          not playing
```

I have 2 new columns called `Headline_Player` and `Status`. The `Headline_Player` is the words before the (text) in the `Headline` column, but that is not always true in my large dataset (**Headline example:** Unfortunately to hear that LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday). I want to search the `Player Name` column for matches with the names before the (text) in the `Headline` column. I believe searching the `Player Name` column to match any first/last name in the `Headline` column then placed into the `Headline_Player`. If other ways are possible, that will work too. This can be done something like this?:

```
def any_words_included(x):
    return any(y in x["Headline"] for y in x["Player Name"].split())

df = df[df.apply(any_words_included, axis=1)]
```

Also notice that the `Status` column is all of the words after the (text) in the `Headline` column.

Can the **"I want to convert my original dataframe to this (NEW):"** be done with the criteria I stated? I can clarify more in-depth if needed.

Comment: It seems you have asked something similar to this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str.extract to extract all matches using pattern,

```
df = df.assign(**df['Headline'].str.extract('(?P<Headline_Player>.*)\s\((?P<Location>.*)\)\s(?P<Status>.*)'))
df = df.dropna()
df['Injury/Rest'] = np.where(df['Location'].eq('rest'), 'Rest', 'Injury')



    Player Name     Headline                                    Headline_Player Location    Status                  Injury/Rest
1   LeBron James    LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday      LeBron James    groin   probable for Thursday   Injury
3   LeBron James    Kyrie Irving (groin) plans to play on Tuesday   Kyrie Irving    groin   plans to play on Tuesday    Injury
4   LeBron James    LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday        LeBron James    rest    questionable Tuesday    Rest
5   LeBron James    LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday       LeBron James    leg     will start on Saturday  Injury
```

Edit: To handle the edge case like Unfortunately to hear that LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday), you can use the regex to extract two strings separated by space. This will strictly work if the name is in the form of two strings.

```
df.assign(**df['Headline'].str.extract('(?P<Headline_Player>\w+\s\w+)\s\((?P<Location>.*)\)\s(?P<Status>.*)'))
```

Comment: Nice! Much simpler.

Comment: This works for most of the rows, but what situations like (Headline example: Unfortunately to hear that LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday)? I am getting "Unfortunately to hear that LeBron James" in the headline_player column.

Comment: The player name and headline doesnt always match (LeBron James   Kevin Love (hip) is questionable) so one cant match the two to find the headline_player

Comment: You can change the regex to df.assign(**df['Headline'].str.extract('(?P<Headline_Player>\w+\s\w+)\s\((?P<Location>.*)\)\s(?P<Status>.*)'))

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't believe it fixed the situation. Here is a Headline example: **LeBron James getting (rest) on Tuesday**. The headline_player column is giving me: **LeBron James getting**. Is there a way to reference all of the output in the headline_player column to match the first/last name to the player name column? So the output for headline_player is only Lebron James since that's referenced in the player name column.

Comment: Regex expects a pattern and if your data is so varied, regex won't work

Comment: After your edit, it cleans it up more with a slight issue. Headline example: **LeBron James might sit out to (rest) on Friday**. The headline_player is coming up as: **out to**. I am wondering if there's a way to reference the player name column to match by first and/or last name in the headline column to correctly have Lebron James in the new headline_player column.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df_new = df[df.Headline.str.contains('\(')].copy()
df_new['Headline_Player'] = df_new.Headline.apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
df_new['Location']=df.Headline.str.extract('\((.*)\)')[0]
df_new['Injury/Rest'] = np.where(df_new['Location'].eq('rest'), 'Rest', 'Injury')
df_new['Status'] = df_new.Headline.apply(lambda x: x.split(')')[1])
df_new
```

**Output**

```
Player Name     Headline                                      Headline_Player   Location    Injury/Rest     Status
LeBron James    LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday    LeBron James      groin   Injury  probable for Thursday
LeBron James    Kyrie Irving (groin) plans to play on Tuesday Kyrie Irving      groin   Injury  plans to play on Tuesday
LeBron James    LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday      LeBron James      rest    Rest    questionable Tuesday
LeBron James    LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday     LeBron James      leg     Injury  will start on Saturday
LeBron James    Kevin Love (hip) is questionable              Kevin Love        hip     Injury  is questionable
Ryan Anderson   Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday Anderson          flu     Injury  returns against Cavs on Sunday
Ryan Anderson   Anderson (rest) not playing                   Anderson          rest    Rest    not playing
```

Comment: I am getting the error `IndexError: list index out of range` for the `df_new['Status']` line.

Comment: There should be a `(` & some text after the bracket, else you will get this error. Check if all the lines in the the `Headline` column have open & closed parenthesis.

Comment: This works for most of the rows, but what situations like (Headline example: Unfortunately to hear that LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday)? I am getting "Unfortunately to hear that LeBron James" in the headline_player column.

Comment: as @Vaishali mentioned, we need to have a pattern, else it is too much for `split` & `regex`.